# How can I convert my JSON to CSV using jq?

Tags: json, perl, shell, csv, jq

I have the following JSON data:

```
{"id":"111","case":"Y","custom":{"speech invoked":"no","input method":"hard","session ID":"420"}}
```

How can I convert it to CSV format using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) so my result looks like this?

```
id,case,session Id,speech invoked,input method

111,Y,420,no,hard
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
{(.id),(.case),(.custom."session Id"),(.custom."speech invoked"),(.custom."input method")}
```

If not possible any perl or shell solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Perl and its JSON module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use JSON;

my $input = << '__JSON__';
{"id":"111","case":"Y","custom":{"speech invoked":"no","input method":"hard","session ID":"420"}}
__JSON__

my $struct = decode_json($input);

my @header = grep ! ref $struct->{$_}, keys %$struct;
push @header, map keys %{ $struct->{$_} },
              grep ref $struct->{$_},
              keys %$struct;

my @row = grep ! ref, values %$struct;
push @row, map values %$_, grep ref, values %$struct;

say join ',', @header;
say join ',', @row;
```

Comment: I'd still want to use Text::CSV_XS to create the output just in case some of the data includes things like spaces, quotes, commas, etc.

Comment: @Tanktalus: Sure. Just tweak the last two lines.

Comment: This doesn't use `jq` like the question asks.

Comment: Not sure why this solution is downvoted. `jq` is definitely preferred over Perl, but the question says `any perl or shell solution is appreciated.`

Answer (score 22):

Building upon Joe Harris' answer, you can use the @csv filter so that strings are properly quoted and escaped when necessary :

```
jq -r '[.case, .custom."speech invoked", .custom."input method"] | @csv'
```

Comment: Looks better than the join but always produces double quotes around the values.

Answer (score 18):

Using perl wasn't a good solution for me but after a bit of trial and error I figured out you can do it with just `jq` using the `join()` operator.

First make an array of the output you need, then join the array elements using commas.

```
jq -r '[.case, .custom."speech invoked", .custom."input method"] | join(", ")'
```

Enjoy. :)

Comment: I left off `.custom."session ID"` so that people can see the `join()` without scrolling.

Answer (score 12):

Using jq, you can use this filter:

```
with_entries(select(.key != "custom")) + .custom
    | to_entries
    | map(.key), map(.value)
    | @csv
```

Just note that written this way, the "custom" properties will always be written in the end, no matter what order the properties are in.

Comment: This is cool because it gets the keys automatically without knowing them in advance and it outputs column headers. But the problem is that the headers are *repeated* for every row. If you have variable input you could safely output only the values but if the input is variable you'll need the headers. Stash the input and output the headers only into your file first and then append the values in a second pass. Will prevent piping the output to gzip though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.  If `data.json` contains the sample data then

```
jq -M -s -r 'map(.+.custom|del(.custom)) | (.[0]|keys_unsorted), (.[]|[.[]]) | join(",")' data.json
```

will produce

```
id,case,speech invoked,input method,session ID
111,Y,no,hard,420
```