# How to add a header to CSV export in jq?

Tags: json, csv, jq

I'm taking a modified command from the `jq` [tutorial](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/):

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' \
| jq -r -c '.[] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name} | [.[]] | @csv'
```

Which does `csv` export well, but missing the headers as the top:

```
"Fix README","Nicolas Williams"
"README: send questions to SO and Freenode","Nicolas Williams"
"usage() should check fprintf() result (fix #771)","Nicolas Williams"
"Use jv_mem_alloc() in compile.c (fix #771)","Nicolas Williams"
"Fix header guards (fix #770)","Nicolas Williams"
```

How can I add the header (in this case `message,name`) at the top? (I know it's possible manually, but how to do it within `jq`?)

Comment: Some of my [CSV/TSV utils based on jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/48#issuecomment-55744660).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/657249/552644 this works good to me and simple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on Anton's comments on Jeff Mercado's answer, this snippet will get the key names of the properties of the first element and output them as an array before the rows, thus using them as headers. If different rows have different properties, then it won't work well; then again, neither would the resulting CSV.

`map({message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}) | (.[0] | to_entries | map(.key)), (.[] | [.[]]) | @csv`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Santiago! I just discovered that this method sorts headers by name but doesn't sort respective columns. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: For the time being I workaround the "sorted headers" issue by naming the heading with prefix "c1_", "c2_", "c3_", etc. Not elegant but works. Would be good to know a proper way to add header using map, without auto-sorted header though!

Comment: The solution in this thread has solved it for me properly (without the workaround). It does the same thing but without sorting the keys. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/48#issuecomment-12398967

Comment: In the more general case, if you can get your JSON reduced to key-value pairs in an array with no nesting, e.g. `[{"name":"Bob", "city":"Toronto", "country":"Canada"}...]`, then you can just do `. |(.[0] | to_entries | map(.key)), (.[] | [.[]]) | @csv`

Answer (score 53):

Just add the header text in an array in front of the values.

```
["Commit Message","Committer Name"], (.[].commit | [.message,.committer.name]) | @csv
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! Any way to make it without repeating headings to take care about cases when you have to modify the selected columns?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's much you can do there. You'll need to add a header column for every value you want.  Do you have a specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm planning to use it in multiple examples, so the original example is the right pattern. I tried to play with `map()` function as in yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/27132468/911945 , but no success.

Answer (score 4):

While I fully realize OP was looking for a *purely jq* answer, I found this question looking for *any* answer. So, let me offer one I found (and found useful) to others like me.

1. `sudo apt install moreutils` - if you don't have them yet. [Moreutils website](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).
2. `echo "Any, column, name, that, is, not, in, your, json, object" | cat - your.csv | sponge your.csv`

Disadvantages: requires `moreutils` package, is not just `jq`-reliant, so some would understandably say less elegant.

Advantages: you choose your headers, not your JSON keys. Also, *pure `jq`* ways are bothered by the sorting of the keys, [depending on your version](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/561).

#### How does it work?

1. echo outputs your header
2. cat - takes echo output from stdin (cause -) and conCATenates it with your csv file
3. sponge waits until that is done and writes the result to same file, overwriting it.

#### But you could do it with `tee` without having to install any packages!

No, you could not, as [Kos excellently demonstrates here](https://askubuntu.com/a/752451/72260). Not unless you're fine with loosing your csv at some point.

Comment: " pure jq ways are bothered by the sorting of the keys" - this is only true of defective or presumptuous programs.

Comment: Why not just echo the text as JSON text , into jq,  without moreutils ?

Comment: You don't need extra tools, just use `ed`. E.g. `<<<$'0a\nAny, column, name, that, is, not, in, your, json, object\n.\nw' ed - your.csv`.