# Convert a flat JSON to a TSV file with column headers

Tags: json, jq

I am reformatting some JSON with JQ into a TSV file.  I am able to create a TSV with the values only, but I cannot figure out how to include a single row with the key values as column headers?

Sample input:

```
{
"id":"1234",
"host":"6789",
"proto":"UDP",
"location":"Boston",
"timestamp":"2020-12-01T14:18:45.717Z",
"src_ip":"192.168.3.70",
"dest_ip":"8.8.8.8",
"dest_port":53,
"message":"Some Information",
"severity":1,
"details":"Some Details",
"categories":["a","b","c"]
}
```

Desired output:

```
"location\ttimestamp\tsrc_ip\tdest_ip\tdest_port"
"Boston\t2020-12-01T15:13:16.242Z\t10.8.25.63\t10.8.1.3\t445"
"Atlanta\t2020-12-01T15:11:15.929Z\t10.8.25.63\t10.80.1.3\t445"
"Chicago\t2020-12-01T15:09:45.271Z\t10.34.196.12\t10.8.1.3\t445"
```

This statement gets me close:

```
cat input.json | jq  '. | to_entries 
| map(select(.key=="timestamp"), select(.key=="location"), select(.key=="src_ip"), select(.key=="dest_ip"), select(.key=="dest_port"))
| map(.key), map(.value) 
| @tsv'
```

But the header line is repeated in the output:

```
"location\ttimestamp\tsrc_ip\tdest_ip\tdest_port"
"Boston\t2020-12-01T15:13:16.242Z\t10.8.25.63\t10.8.1.3\t445"
"location\ttimestamp\tsrc_ip\tdest_ip\tdest_port"
"Atlanta\t2020-12-01T15:11:15.929Z\t10.8.25.63\t10.80.1.3\t445"
```

Is there a way to print the keys on the first row only, and then print only the values on the remaining rows, using only JQ?

Comment: I am guessing this is the same question but for CSV so you might be able to adapt it...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015555/how-to-add-a-header-to-csv-export-in-jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make such a flat object JSON to a TSV format, using the `@tsv` function would be to do

```
jq -n ' ["location", "timestamp", "src_ip", "dest_ip", "dest_port"] as $hdr | 
        $hdr, ( inputs | [ .[ $hdr[] ] ] ) | @tsv'
```

This works, by reusing the key fields as in the header, `.[ $hdr[] ]` is a simple trick to expand values of each of the literal fields in the `hdr` array to their corresponding values in the object (see [Generic Object Index](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#GenericObjectIndex:.%5B%3Cstring%3E%5D)). By surrounding it in the brackets, you get the selected field values in an array. With this array collected and the header array, apply the `@tsv` function to get the tabular form.

[jq play snippet - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/x3eHtqM1M-)

Comment: Execellent, that worked.  And I now see that I need to teach myself how to use variables in JQ.  Thank you!