# why not print csv headers?

Tags: csv, centos, jq

CentOS, jq

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

I want to export json to csv.
I use tool **jq** for this.

Here example of json.

```json
{
  "page": {
    "id": "kctbh9vrtdwd",
    "name": "GitHub",
    "url": "https://www.githubstatus.com",
    "time_zone": "Etc/UTC",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-27T16:56:02.461Z"
  },
  "status": {
    "indicator": "none",
    "description": "All Systems Operational"
  }
}
```

I get by

```
curl -s https://www.githubstatus.com/api/v2/status.json
```

Here convert json to csv.

```
curl -s https://www.githubstatus.com/api/v2/status.json | jq -r '.page | [.id, .name] | @csv'
```

And here is the result:

```
"kctbh9vrtdwd","GitHub"
```

But why not print csv headers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a header to CSV export in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015555/how-to-add-a-header-to-csv-export-in-jq)

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a lot of noise on the SO page that is provided as a link in one of the comments,
so here are two *safe* jq-only solutions ("safe" in the sense that it does not matter how the keys are ordered in the input JSON):

1. Manually add the headers

```
["id", "name"],
(.page | [.id, .name])
| @csv
```

2. Include the headers based on the specification of the relevant columns

```
["id", "name"] as $headers
| $headers, (.page | [.[$headers[]]])
| @csv
```

Comment: I try this "curl -s https://www.githubstatus.com/api/v2/status.json | jq ["id", "name"], '.page | [.id, .name] | @csv'" but get error: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[id,   
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Your attempt is missing the parentheses.

Comment: I try this: "curl -s githubstatus.com/api/v2/status.json | jq ["id", "name"], (.page | [.id, .name]) | @csv" , but get error bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: You either need to learn how to enter bash commands, or put the jq program into a file and use the -f command-line option.