# duplicate headers after convert to csv

Tags: json, csv, jq

In json file:

```
{
  "issues": [
    {
      "key": "key_1",
      "component": "my_component",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 1,
        "endLine": 11,
        "startOffset": 111,
        "endOffset": 1111
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "key2",
      "component": "my component 2",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 2,
        "endLine": 22,
        "startOffset": 222,
        "endOffset": 2222
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "my_key3",
      "component": "my component 3",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 548,
        "endLine": 548,
        "startOffset": 14,
        "endOffset": 15
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert to csv and add headers.

I try this:

```
jq -r '.issues[] | ["key","component", "textRange"], [.key,.component, .textRange[]] | @csv' test.issues.json
```

Result:

```
"key","component","textRange"
"key_1","my_component",1,11,111,1111
"key","component","textRange"
"key2","my component 2",2,22,222,2222
"key","component","textRange"
"my_key3","my component 3",548,548,14,15
```

Why headers are duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a header to CSV export in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015555/how-to-add-a-header-to-csv-export-in-jq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the headers inside the iteration. Pull them up front

```sh
["key","component", "textRange"],
(.issues[] | [.key,.component, .textRange[]])
| @csv
```

```
"key","component","textRange"
"key_1","my_component",1,11,111,1111
"key2","my component 2",2,22,222,2222
"my_key3","my component 3",548,548,14,15
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6sazNT-Jqn)

Comment: Why would you want to answer a well known duplicate instead of closing it as such? As a frequent visitor on the tag, you should encourage such actions

Comment: @pmf I try this: jq -r ["key","component", "textRange"], (.issues[] | [.key,.component, .textRange[]]) | @csv test.json  . And get error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Inian As you can see, people sometimes need more assistance than just blaming them not having searched extensively or not having understood the root of their failure.

Comment: @Alexei It seems you are missing the quotes around your jq filter: `jq -r '…'`

Comment: How simple could it be to search `json jq headers csv`. I got the link I posted in the first hit at search

Comment: @Inian Yet, the OP struggles on a different level. People *are* different. What is simple for you might not be for others (and vice versa). Thus, answering a question in as many ways as possible (ie. giving a solution **and** hinting them to other sources) is the most respectful way of interaction I can imagine. Blaming someone not to find simple the same things you do, is not.

Comment: @Inian and Pmf, I see both of your points. I just voted to close this as a dupe because it's solidly a duplicate of Q/A Inian linked to... Pmf I don't see this answer adding anything to the discussion or helping OP think about the problem any differently... you just gave them a customized solution with about the same general answer as the other answer. Inian, I think beyond just linking to a valid answer, point out what the answer will mean to OP, "Oh, you need put your header up front, see this answer here for details...", will probably be more helpful, but no guarantees.