# defined csv output from Bash curl web api request

Tags: shell, curl, webapi

I am new to shell scripting and WebAPI curl requests. I am trying to get a defined csv from multiple curl request such as :

```
for i in {01..10}
do
   printf "\ntesting row_$i:\n"
   curl -X POST "http://120.0.0.1:8000/v1/APIreturn" \
     -H "accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d @test/test_$i.json
   printf "\n"
done
```

i simply run the above shell script as :

```
bash curl_test.sh -> save_results.txt
```

this results in string of returns from each call (1,2...10) which is not neat and structured. 
output comes out as 
[image]

i want to instead save results in a neat csv where different endpoints of API are different columns and rows are appended to get all the curl requests from 1,2...10

desired is :

[image]

i have tried 
`bash curl_test.sh -> save_results.csv` but that doesn't give the structure

Comment: Include your curl output etc as text in your question, not images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31181094/10678955 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163845